# MySQL 5.6 Error 1118 Row Size Too Large Fix Not Working (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am running XAMPP with MySQL 5.6, and I'm also accessing mySQL through phpMyAdmin.

I have a table with 250 columns, and it's a mix of longtext, varchar, and tinyint.

All my varchars are set to about 30 length, tinyint is 2 length, and the rest are longtexts.

I'm getting the following error when I start trying to update some rows with a lot of text. (only about 200 characters more than what it had before)

```
#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

I've looked all over for solutions, but nothing seems to work.  I already increased my innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size and restarted the mySQL server and it seems to start up fine.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M  (originally was 16M)
innodb_log_file_size = 32M (originally was 5M)
```

However I'm still getting the error when trying to insert or update rows with a lot of text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: You might consider restructuring your database. I recall having the same issue and we ended up splitting the table into multiple ones thus reducing the size of each row. Think about what data you need on every query and what might be OK to simply `join`ed when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best and only advice I got was from ferdynator.  Thanks!

I split the table up, and just created a view of all tables joined up and now it's much better.